# governor can't be set

Tags: rhel

RHEL 7.

I'm trying to set cpufreq_performance governor but by some reason it doesn't work:

```
[root@localhost]# cpupower frequency-set -g cpufreq_performance
invalid or unknown argument
[root@localhost]# cpupower frequency-info --governors
analyzing CPU 0:
```

Why I can not set `cpufreq_performance` governor? Why I can not print list of available governors?

---

It's interesting but it seems my CPUs already opperating on the maximum Turbo frequency even on idle system. CPUs below are Xeon E5-2640 v1. if "Freq" is "current", "live" value then my CPU's are "turboboosted"

```
[root@localhost]# cpupower monitor
              |Nehalem                    || SandyBridge        || Mperf
PKG |CORE|CPU | C3   | C6   | PC3  | PC6  || C7   | PC2  | PC7  || C0   | Cx   | Freq
   0|   0|   0|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.18| 99.82|  2789
   0|   0|  12|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.01| 99.99|  2790
   0|   1|   1|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.03| 99.97|  2789
   0|   1|  13|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.01| 99.99|  2797
   0|   2|   2|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2737
   0|   2|  14|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2799
   0|   3|   3|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.01| 99.99|  2778
   0|   3|  15|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2788
   0|   4|   4|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.02| 99.98|  2786
   0|   4|  16|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2791
   0|   5|   5|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.01| 99.99|  2791
   0|   5|  17|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2784
   1|   0|   6|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.02| 99.98|  2790
   1|   0|  18|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2790
   1|   1|   7|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2803
   1|   1|  19|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.09| 99.91|  2790
   1|   2|   8|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2791
   1|   2|  20|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2783
   1|   3|   9|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.01| 99.99|  2791
   1|   3|  21|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2789
   1|   4|  10|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2791
   1|   4|  22|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2792
   1|   5|  11|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2793
   1|   5|  23|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|  0.00|  0.00||  0.00|100.00|  2789
```

**upd**

```
[root@localhost]# cpupower frequency-set -g performance
Setting cpu: 0
Error setting new values. Common errors:
- Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
- Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
- Trying to set an invalid policy?
- Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
   for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency
   or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?
```

**upd2**

```
[root@localhost]# cpupower frequency-info --driver
analyzing CPU 0:
[root@localhost]# ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0
cache  crash_notes  crash_notes_size  driver  firmware_node  microcode  node0  power  subsystem  thermal_throttle  topology  uevent
[root@localhost]# cpupower --version
cpupower 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64.debug
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please
[root@localhost]# systemctl status cpupower.service
cpupower.service - Configure CPU power related settings
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cpupower.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: With more recent versions of `cpupower` you have to run `cpupower frequency-set -g performance`. Not sure why it doesn't list the available governors... The _Freq_ column should be "live", yes. On my laptop (Sandy Bridge) some cores are also turboboosted (at idle) when using the `performance` governor. What's your kernel version ? Also, is your system using the `intel_pstate` driver ? If so there are only two governors and the default is `performance`.

Comment: i'm using latest kernel version. i'm not sure about `intel_pstate`, I can check if you know how to do this.

Comment: @don_crissti thanks, added "upd2". it seems cpupower service is disabled?

Comment: Is this happening with a "real" install or in a virtual machine ? There is no `cpufreq` directory under your `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0` and as per the [Intel docs](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/comment/1716807/how-to-change-frequency-on-linux-pub.txt): _If the directory /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq exists, speed is controllable.  -- If it does not exist, you may need to go to the BIOS and turn on EIST and any other C and P state control and visibility, then reboot._